# is there way to pass argument from another command

Tags: bash

how can I pass the output of `whoami` as argument for another command such as

```
whoami
#root

top -u root
```

I want to do this in one line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use a *command substitution*:

```
top -u "$(whoami)"
```

However, and in this case, you may also use one of the variables `$USER` and `$LOGNAME` to do the same thing, avoiding calling the `whoami` utility (or `id -un`).

```
top -u "$USER"
```

Comment: what is the difference between your first command and 
$(whoami) i.e with quotations and without

Comment: `$USER` and `$LOGNAME` are changable by the caller and shouldn't be trusted.  `whoami` (depending on the OS) may call a sequence such as `getuid()` and `getpwuid()` to get the name, so is more reliable.

Comment: @StephenHarris that is correct `sudo echo $USER $LOGNAME` gives the same as `echo $USER $LOGNAME`

Comment: @User1984 The difference is not that great in this specific case. Generally, an unquoted expansion will by default be split on spaces, tabs and newlines, into words. Each word will undergo filename globbing if they contain filename globbing characters (such as `*`). You almost always want to avoid this splitting and globbing, so all expansions should be double quoted.

Comment: @User1984 Try `sudo bash -c 'echo "$LOGNAME"'` instead (in your example, the variables are expanded _before `sudo` is called_). What Stephen in getting at is that a user is allowed to _change_ these variables.

Comment: @Kusalananda I see, thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 1):

One simpĺe liner

```
top -u "$(whoami)"
```

Comment: this works thanks, I can also add text to it directly